# Discord unknown application command while delete application command with discord endpoint

Tags: discord, bots, endpoint

I am using js code provide by offical guide to write my bot.

I want to remove those test slash command that I created with the end point memtion here:-

Delete global command https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#delete-global-application-command

But I goot unknown application command error. Below is the code that I am using, how I get the command id and the error message.

> applications/1095761328834089020/commands/1104966880478896129

```
export async function DeleteGlobalCommands(appId, commands) {
  // API endpoint to overwrite global commands
  const endpoint = `applications/${appId}/commands/${commands}`;

  console.log(commands);

  try {
    // Delete global command https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#delete-global-application-command
    await DiscordRequest(endpoint,{ method: 'DELETE'});
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

I copy the command Id by Server setting -> integrations -> [my bot name] -> right click command -> copy command ID

Error

```
404
{ message: 'Unknown application command', code: 10063 }
Error: {"message":"Unknown application command","code":10063}
    at DiscordRequest (file:///C:/gitlab/discordBot/utils.js:37:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async DeleteGlobalCommands (file:///C:/gitlab/discordBot/utils.js:63:5)
    at async file:///C:/gitlab/discordBot/app.js:43:13
```

Please help.